# Use of the passive voice in the verb exerceo

Tags: passive-voice

I am doing a lesson and the sentence and caption is as follows:

[image]

**Robustus est quia exercetur.**

Which seems intended to mean "He is strong because he trains." However, I don't understand why they would put exercetur in the passive voice. I would have expected exercet, the active voice. Is there some non-standard use of the passive here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English *exercise* doesn't change if it's used transitively or intransitively, but that's not the case for the Latin word it comes from. As Lewis and Short (and I'm sure other dictionaries) say, [*exerceo*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=exerceo&la=la#lexicon) in the active means 'to exercise something,' whereas in the passive and used intransitively it means 'to exercise, practice, or train [oneself].'

Therefore if you had *exercet*, you would expect an object. See e.g. the first Cicero passage listed:

> me adolescentem multos annos...[Hortensius] exercuit, Cic. *Brut*. 64, 230
>
> Hortensius trained adolescent me for many years...

In your sentence, *exerceo* doesn't have an object or an agent, so you can assume it's being used in this intransitive sense, which is often called the 'middle voice.' Otherwise you might see *se* as an object of *exercet*, 'to exercise [oneself].'

Comment: Thanks, incidentally how is multos annos "for many years"? I would have expected "in multis annis" or something like that.

Comment: @TylerDurden It's called the accusative of duration (or acc. of time). No prepositions are necessary for it, though you will sometimes see *per*: https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/expressions-time